# \frac command: height of the numerator vs height of denominator

Tags: fractions

I have the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
 \underline{W}^1_{\,q,\rho} =  \left\lceil
 \frac{\sum\limits_{v \in
Q, v \neq q}\underline{C}_{\,v} + \sum\limits_{i=\rho+1}^{|\Omega^{(U)}_q|}p_i+
\sum\limits_{i \in U \backslash \Omega^{(U)}_q}p_i%
+\underline{TT}_{\,q, \rho} }{m-1}
 \right\rceil\,,
\end{equation}
```

that is rendered as:

[image]

As you may see, the numerator height is the same as the denominator. I don't need all this waste of empty space.
How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: You could use the `nicefrac` package to circumvent this issue.

Comment: Consider `\frac{1}{m-1}` before the long expression in the numerator.

Comment: @Ruben I got a look at the commands of the package. It seems that all the fractions provided by the package use a sort of slash! Am I wrong? Please, can you provide the command I should use?

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't understand really. Please, can you post an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not a real answer to your question, see below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underline{W}^1_{\,q,\rho} =
\biggl\lceil \frac{1}{m-1}
  \biggl(\,
  \sum_{v \in Q, v \neq q}\underline{C}_{\,v} +
  \sum_{i=\rho+1}^{|\Omega^{(U)}_q|}p_i +
  \sum_{i \in U \setminus \Omega^{(U)}_q}p_i +
  \underline{TT}_{\,q, \rho}
  \biggr)
\biggr\rceil,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you don't need `\limits` when in a display; also `\backslash` should be `\setminus`. Note also that `\left` and `\right` would give an inferior result, because they would cover also the big upper limit, which is not necessary.

You can easily adapt this for a two column format:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\underline{W}^1_{\,q,\rho} =
\biggl\lceil \frac{1}{m-1}
  \biggl(\,
  \sum_{v \in Q, v \neq q}\underline{C}_{\,v} + {}\\
  \sum_{i=\rho+1}^{|\Omega^{(U)}_q|}p_i +
  \sum_{i \in U \setminus \Omega^{(U)}_q}p_i +
  \underline{TT}_{\,q, \rho}
  \biggr)
\biggr\rceil,
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does that horrible result appear? Because the main fraction line is set on the “formula axis” and fences are set to cover the material *and* be centered on the axis.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the above issues and for the explanations.

Comment: @Roby I added also the “two column” way.

Answer (score 6):

While the other answers may be preferable alternatives to answer your question, you did mention "I don't need all this waste of empty space."  Here is a different way to avoid the empty space, while preserving your original intent.  The `\stretchleftright` macro of `scalerel` package using glyph stretching to simulate a `\left\...\right` effect, but only as far as necessary to match the vertical extent of the middle argument.  In this case, the optional argument of [300] tells the macro to not let the aspect ratio of the stretch exceed 300%, increasing the width as necessary to maintain it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \underline{W}^1_{\,q,\rho} =  \stretchleftright[300]{\lceil}{%
 \frac{\sum\limits_{v \in
Q, v \neq q}\underline{C}_{\,v} + \sum\limits_{i=\rho+1}^{|\Omega^{(U)}_q|}p_i+
\sum\limits_{i \in U \backslash \Omega^{(U)}_q}p_i%
+\underline{TT}_{\,q, \rho} }{m-1}
}{\rceil}\,,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this is easier to read than the fraction you're trying to write:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \underline{W}^1_{\,q,\rho} =  \left\lceil
\frac{1}{m-1} \left(
\sum\limits_{v \in
Q, v \neq q}\underline{C}_{\,v} + \sum\limits_{i=\rho+1}^{|\Omega^{(U)}_q|}p_i+
\sum\limits_{i \in U \backslash \Omega^{(U)}_q}p_i%
+\underline{TT}_{\,q, \rho} \right)
 \right\rceil\,,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point. However, sometimes the a double-column template is used in many journals. Thus, this solution could not be compliant with the available column width. I should scale the font size, but I guess it is not allowed by the editorial office.

Comment: Whatever you do be sure to use @egreg 's improvements.

Comment: I'll do it! I'm sorry I cannot upvote!