# How to reduce the space enclosed in parentheses?

Tags: equations, parenthesis

The following lines gives me more space below E^2 inside the parentheses. How to reduce this extra space. Also, the square (2) is above enclosing parentheses.

```
\begin{equation*}
\left[\frac{{\left(\vec{A} - \displaystyle\frac{b}{c} \vec{D} \right)}^2}{E^2} \right]^{1/2}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: space_brac]

Comment: The extra space in the denominator is answered at this link. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168394/frac-command-height-of-the-numerator-vs-height-of-denominator

Comment: i would never use `\displaystyle` in the _middle_ of an expression. If you must use it then it should almost always be at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mind something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

% for show equation only
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}c<{$}@{}}
\dfrac{\left(\vec{A} - \dfrac{b}{c}\vec{D}\right)}{E^2}
    \end{tabular}\right]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

**Addendum:** More simple code is, if instead of `tabular` the environment  `array` is used:

```
\begin{equation}
    \left[\begin{array}{@{} c @{}
    }
\dfrac{\left(\vec{A} - \dfrac{b}{c}\vec{D}\right)}{E^2}
    \end{array}\right]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
```

Result is the same ase before.

Comment: This looks much better but then there are spaces before and after fraction.

Comment: Ups, I forgot on this spaces ... see edit of my answer.

Comment: Why not an `array` instead of going in math mode in a `tabular`?

Comment: I just prepare addendum with array. With tabular I have on "stock" :-)

Comment: @egreg Shouldn't \left[ \right] just encloses what is needed. Why the extra spaces with my approach.

Comment: @raj The fences inserted with `\left` and `\right` are vertically symmetric with respect to the main fraction line.

Comment: What is purpose of environment `array` why does it work? Could you update your post please with some explanations? Thanks!

Comment: @Yola, array is for settings arrays (like matrices, tables etc). it benefits over `tabular` is preserving math environment in cells if it is in it. see http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Array_(LaTeX_environment) and  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `delarray`, but I think it's much better the second way I propose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

Here's a fraction with very large numerator
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}\lbrack{@{}c@{}}\rbrack
\dfrac{\left(\vec{A} - \dfrac{b}{c} \vec{D} \right)^2}{E^2}
\end{array}^{1/2}
\end{equation*}
but it's much better to write it in a different way
\begin{equation*}
\left[\frac{1}{E^2}\left(\vec{A} - \frac{b}{c} \vec{D} \right)^2\right]^{1/2}
\end{equation*}
so the terms are better aligned with the formula axis.

\end{document}
```

[image]